How to change secondarty Axis Title on devexpress winform chart?
I am drawing charts via devexpress library in a winform based project. The title of the vertical line is the vertical direction. Do you know how to change it to landscape?
I checked all of DevExpress's Docs and also checked the provided designer, but I couldn't find any property to change it to landscape.
What part did I miss?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
